# Cygwin $0 not working as exptected

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have an odd behavior of $0 under cygwin.

In my script, I do `echo "$0"`, and get as output `-bash` instead of the pathname. However, if I do realpath $0, i get the actual path. Why is that, and do other people encounter this, too?

I am trying to source the script, does this change things?

Comment: You may want to check: [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/1983854)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sourcing is the reason. Sourcing does not start a different process, so things like `$0` will continue to have their values when the script is being `source`d.

Here is a script `myname`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$0"
```

Here is the sourcing:

```
$ source myname
-bash
```

And here is running the script:

```
$ ./myname
./myname
```

There you are!

Update: This is not `cygwin` specific. All shells should behave this way, by design.